# How to solve the security of data transmission between Prometheus federated clusters in public network?

Tags: prometheus

I have several network isolated production environments on different cloud. 
And now I want to build Prometheus federate to scrape all the metric to on place. The question is How to solve the security of data transmission between Prometheus federated clusters in public network?

Comment: Do you need federation or a cluster ? Federation is not intended to be used as a way to get all of the data. For a cluster, you would rather use [Thanos](https://thanos.io/) or a Prometheus derivative like [Cortex](https://cortexmetrics.io/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe mutual TLS is your answer. Your server would use a tls certificate and then you would configure your prometheus federation to use the same certs and they will mutually authenticate each other.